# How to calculate percentage in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a newbie to R and I have a data frame which contains the following fields:

```
day  place  hour   time_spent  count
 1     1      1       1         120
 1     1      1       2         100
 1     1      1       3          90
 1     1      1       4          80
```

So my aim is to calculate the time spent in each place where 75% of the vehicles to cross the place.So from this data frame I generate the below data frame by

```
 day  place  hour   time_spent  count  cum_count   percentage
     1     1      1       1         120      120       30.7%  
     1     1      1       2         100      220       56.4%
     1     1      1       3          90      310       79%
     1     1      1       4          80      390       100%

df$cum_count=cumsum(df$count)
df$percentage=cumsum(df$percentage)

for(i in 1:length(df$percentage)){

       if(df$percentage[i]>75%){
          low time=df$time_spent[i-1]
          high_time=df$time_spent[i]
           }
      }
```

So which means that 75% of vehicles are spending 2-3 minutes in the place 1.But now I have a data frame like this which is for all the places and for all the days.

```
day  place  hour   time_spent  count
 1     1      1       1         120
 1     1      1       2         100
 1     1      1       3          90
 1     1      1       4          80
 1     2      1       1         220
 1     2      1       2         100
 1     2      1       3          90
 1     2      1       4          80
 1     3      1       1         100
 1     3      1       2         80
 1     3      1       3         90
 1     3      1       4         100
 2     1      1       1         120
 2     1      1       2         100
 2     1      1       3          90
 2     1      1       4          80
 2     2      1       1         220
 2     2      1       2         100
 2     2      1       3          90
 2     2      1       4          80
 2     3      1       1         100
 2     3      1       2         80
 2     3      1       3         90
 2     3      1       4         100
```

How is it possible to calculate the high time and low time for each place?Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `max` and `min` functions ought to do the trick here. Although you could also do `summary` to get median, mean, etc in one go. I'd also recommend the `quantile` function for these percentages. As usually the case with R the tricky part if getting the data in the correct format.

Say you want the total time spent at each place:

```
index <- sort(unique(df$place))
times <- as.list(rep(NA, length(index)))
names(times) <- index
for(ii in index){
  counter <- c()
  for(jj in df[df$place==ii,]$time_spent){
    counter <- c(counter, rep(jj, df[df$place==ii,]$count[jj]))
  }
  times[[ii]] <- counter
}
```

Now for each place you can compute the max and min with:

```
lapply(times, max)
lapply(times, min)
```

Similarly you can compute the mean:

```
lapply(times, function(x) sum(x)/length(x))
lapply(times, mean)
```

I think what you want are the quantiles:

```
lapply(times, quantile, 0.75)
```

This would be time by which at least 75% of vehicles had passed though a place, i.e., 75% of vehicles had took this time or less to pass through.

Comment: In ur code `names(times) <- index` is throwing an error as names attribute[87] must be the same length as the vector [2].Why is it so?

Comment: Think I've fixed how `times` is assigned. :)

Comment: Ah, it's a type issue. Edited now.

Comment: Yeah now it is correct but when I use lapply(times,quantile,0.75) it is sometimes showing more than the time_taken.For example it shows the result 10.9 for some places where the vehicle does not spend 10 minutes in the place.Do u have any idea about it?

Comment: The quantile function works more like the `median` than the `mean`, it may round up to the nearest observed value. I've altered the `times` object to adjust for counts. This seems to give values of 3 or 4 as expected.

Comment: It works using the test data (from @Darshan Baral), are there any `NA` or `0` values in the full dataset?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a group by operation

```
library(dplyr)
dfN %>% 
     group_by(day, place) %>% 
     mutate(cum_count = cumsum(count), 
            percentage = 100*cum_count/sum(count),
            low_time = time_spent[which.max(percentage > 75)-1],
             high_time = time_spent[low_time+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question correctly (you want min and max value of time_spent in a place):

```
df %>%
  group_by(place) %>% 
  summarise(min(time_spent),
            max(time_spent))
```

will give you this:

```
place  min(time-spent)  max(time_spent)

1       1                     4

2       1                     4

3       1                     4
```